# How to get rid of several while loops and a better idea of displaying results

Tags: php, mysql

My application requires to create a stock management table which has a lot of items categorised into subgroups. For and idea, the stock management table looks like:

```
                           Location1             Location2                Total
Desktops    // Main Category
Microsoft   //Sub-Category

Windows 7                    23000                 150000                173000
Office 2011                 203300                   3002                206302 
....

Apple       //Sub-Category
OS Snow Leopard              4000                    3000                  7003
OS Lion                     39494                   40034                 79528
...

Tablets    //Main Category
Lenovo     //Sub-Cateogry

LX-243                       3434                   4399                   7833
...
```

This is a visualisation of what the table should look like, now i have a huge mysql query which does that for me, it is scary. In a gist, what i am doing is the following:

1. Select 1st category and start a while loop
   // echo as the main category
2. Select sub-category corresponding to the main category and start a while loop again.
   // echo as the sub-category
3. select all items in the sub-category and start a while loop.
4. select 1st location.
5. select the current item from 3 and the current location from 4 and echo item.
   // echo item names and the quantity in the locations.

**Now my question here is is there a better way to display this than using several while loops, i tried using functions but they are becoming a mess too. Also i couldn't figure out where should i perform the calculations to get the total in the last column.**

Database structure:

```
Category: CategoryID, Description
Sub-Cateogry: Sub-Category_ID, Category_ID, Description
Item: Item_ID, Sub-category_id, Description
Location: Location_ID, Description
Stock_Management: Item_ID, Location_ID, Quantity
```

Code as requested:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select Board_ID, Title from Board where Company_ID = '$company_id' order by Title");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $curr_ID = $row[0];
        $curr_category = $row[1];
        echo "<tr class='sub-heading' style='background: rgba(76, 178, 255, 0.1)'><td colspan='".$count."'>".$curr_category."</td></tr>";
        $sql1 = mysql_query("select Sub_Category_ID, Title from Sub_Category where Category_ID = '$curr_ID' order by Title");
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
            $curr_sub_cat_id = $row1[0];
            $curr_sub_cate = $row1[1];
            echo "<tr style='background: rgba(149, 255, 145, 0.10'><td colspan='".$count."'><b>".$curr_sub_cate."</b></td></tr>";
            $sql2 = mysql_query("select Book_ID, title from Book where sub_category_id = '$curr_sub_cat_id' Order by title");
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
                $curr_book = $row2[0];
                echo "<tr><td>".$row2[1]."</td>";
                $sql4 = mysql_query("select OfficeID, OfficeTitle from Office where OfficeTitle IN ('$locations')");
                while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql4)) {
                    $curr_location = $row3[0];
                    $sql3 = mysql_query("select Quantity from Stock_Management where Book_ID = '$curr_book' and Location_ID = '$curr_location'");
                    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {
                        echo "<td>".$row3[0]."</td>";
                    }   
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: It may be possible to do that with a single query, and a single loop. Please post you db structure.

Comment: when you say select, do you mean executing a query? I thought you already have all the data in memory?

Comment: @mindandmedia Sorry that means executing the query

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Frankly, no.  There's no way to print everything without iterating over it.  Even if you call someone else's function to print it, that's what they're doing.  Exactly what format are you getting your "scary SQL" data in?  Data transformation depends on the data you get.

Also:  You should always post your code.

Comment: add table structure + queries in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: You've missed the first query from your posted code.

Comment: It would be a good idea to decouple your display logic from your business logic. First get all data you want into an appropriate array structure, and then loop over that to echo whatever you need do. This way it will be easier for you to maintain the code and easier for us to focus on what matters.

Comment: @elrado, SQL Fiddle doesn't let me run PHP statements, so can't demonstrate it, sorry.

Comment: You might be needing the equivalent of a pivot table. It's difficult to know without seeing the db structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this -

```
<?php

$locations = array('Location 1', 'Location 2', 'Location 3');
$locationCols = array();
$locationList = array();

foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $locationColName = preg_replace('[^a-z0-9]', '_', strtolower($location));
    $location = mysql_real_escape_string($location);
    $locationCols[] = "SUM(IF(Office.OfficeTitle = '$location', Stock_Management.Quantity, 0)) AS `$locationColName`";
    $locationList[] = "'$location'";
}
$locationCols = implode(', ', $locationCols);
$locationList = implode(',', $locationList);

$sql = "SELECT Board.Title AS BoardTitle, Sub_Category.Title AS SubCatTitle, Book.title AS BookTitle, $locationCols, SUM(Stock_Management.Quantity) AS Total
        FROM Board
        INNER JOIN Sub_Category
            ON Board.Board_ID = Sub_Category.Category_ID
        INNER JOIN Book
            ON Sub_Category.Sub_Category_ID = Book.sub_category_id
        INNER JOIN Office
        LEFT JOIN Stock_Management
            ON Book.Book_ID = Stock_Management.Book_ID
            AND Office.OfficeID = Stock_Management.Location_ID
        WHERE Board.Company_ID = 2
        AND Office.OfficeTitle IN ($locationList)
        GROUP BY Board.Title, Sub_Category.Title, Book.title";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$prevBoard = '';
$prevSubCat = '';

echo '<table>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

    // if new board print board
    if ($prevBoard != $row->BoardTitle) {
        echo '<tr class="sub-heading" style="background: rgba(76, 178, 255, 0.1)"><td colspan="">' . $row->BoardTitle . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $prevBoard = $row->BoardTitle;

    if ($prevSubCat != $row->SubCatTitle) {
        echo '<tr style="background: rgba(149, 255, 145, 0.10)"><td colspan=""><b>' . $row->SubCatTitle . '</b></td></tr>';
    }
    $prevSubCat = $row->SubCatTitle;

    // print product row
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$row->BookTitle}</td>";

    foreach ($locations as $location) {
        $locationColName = preg_replace('[^a-z0-9]', '_', strtolower($location));
        echo "<td>{$row->$locationColName}</td>";
    }

    echo "<td>{$row->Total}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '<table>';
```

Comment: I won't be able to use that as the user has the option to select the locations he wants to view data from. So i cannot use `'Location 1'` etc. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: That is why I said you could build the Location field dynamically based on the location select. How are the locations submitted by the user? Is it an array of location ids?

Comment: They being sent using ajax, `echo $locations` results in `Location1, Location2, Location3` etc.

Comment: And that is the value stored in OfficeTitle?

Comment: Yes, OfficeTitle has `Location1`, `Location2` etc in the table.

Comment: Does this query give you the desired results apart from the location issues?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9006/discussion-between-nnichols-and-namit)